# Relatively positioned right column moves down when unhiding an element in the left column

Tags: jquery, html, css, position, multiple-columns

I am trying to build a registration form for our website and it's going good except one annoying issue. The form has two columns where users input their information. When I began making elements for the first (left) column, it automatically positioned them into the correct spot, so I finished making all the fields and moved onto the second (right) column. I had to position it with relative positioning in order to avoid overflow issues. Now in the left column, I have a dropdown box which unhides a textbox when a certain option is selected. Problem is when the textbox becomes visible, the entire right column moves down. I need that column to stay in place regardless of what's happening in the first column but not have to use absolute positioning. How can this be accomplished? Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q4A2/1/) simulation of my problem.

Please take a look at that fiddle, but since stackoverflow wants it accompanied by code, here's the jQuery script for showing and hiding the textbox:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#text1line").hide();
      $("select[name='select1']").change(function() {
        if ($(this).children("option:selected").attr("id") === "show")
        {
          $("#text1line").show();
        } 
        else 
        {
          $("#text1line").hide();
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use css visibility property instead of display.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#text1line").css('visibility','hidden');
  $("select[name='select1']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).children("option:selected").attr("id") === "show")
    {
    $("#text1line").css('visibility','visible');
    } 
    else 
    {
    $("#text1line").css('visibility','hidden');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: In my actual form moving this would take it out of the normal flow and force me to manually reposition it, correct?

Comment: I have edited my answer and now you don't need to change any html. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Q4A2/6/

Comment: Thanks. This is a nice temporary fix until I can get it working without having a little bit of empty space in my form.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I recommend using floats and setting a width on your left/right columns.  So your css would become something like this:

```
.leftcol, .rightcol {
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bradleytrager/NW9ya/)